# Java "cannot find symbol" error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to make an Uber jar in Intellij and have run across this issue with maven shade. I have looked at other solutions but nothing seems to work. My project is to make a plugin for Minecraft, if that helps at all. I run 'mvn package' or 'mvn compile' and it produces the error below.

Error:

```js
C:\Users\luckycosmos\IdeaProjects\discordMC>mvn compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< me.cosmicluck:discordMC >-----------------------
[INFO] Building discordMC 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ discordMC ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ discordMC ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\Users\luckycosmos\IdeaProjects\discordMC\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[19,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class DiscordHandler
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[21,43] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class DiscordHandler
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[12,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[30,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[52,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[2,43] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[3,43] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[13,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[16,15] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[21,12] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MVWorldManager
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[25,50] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MVWorldManager
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[25,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[29,49] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
  location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[33,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[34,21] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseCore
  location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[31,13] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
  location: class MVManager
[INFO] 19 errors
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.685 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-23T20:28:39-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project discordMC: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[19,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class DiscordHandler
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/DiscordHandler.java:[21,43] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class DiscordHandler
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[12,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[30,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[52,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[1,39] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[2,43] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[3,43] package com.onarandombox.MultiverseCore.api does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[13,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[16,15] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[21,12] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MVWorldManager
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[25,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MVWorldManager
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[25,23] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[29,49] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[33,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/Main.java:[34,21] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseCore
[ERROR]   location: class Main
[ERROR] /C:/Users/luckycosmos/IdeaProjects/discordMC/src/main/java/MVManager.java:[31,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class MultiverseWorld
[ERROR]   location: class MVManager
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

pom.xml:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.cosmicluck</groupId>
    <artifactId>discordMC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!--Spigot API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--Bukkit API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0_365</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I checked my JDK home, everything is correct. I am confused as to why this is happening, I have never seen this happen before. Hopefully I can get some enlightenment on this.

Comment: how is your project folder structure?

Comment: None of those errors look like they come from shade, they are compilation errors in your Java code. You never make it to the shade plugin.  You need to fix the missing dependency(ies).

Comment: There are no missing dependencies. Everything is there, the only thing I can think of is one of them is an external jar file used for the Multiverse api. I can't use maven for multiverse because it gives me a completely different error that I can't fix.